# Socket.io and signed cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io

I'm trying to access cookies in socket.io but it doesn't work, I mean, I can see the cookies but the parse is not correct, I tried this:

```
//Initialisation:
var connect = require('connect');
var cook = require('cookie');
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
     var cookie = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies(cook.parse(socket.handshake.headers['cookie']),secret);
     console.log(cookie);
}
```

And this code makes me this:

```
{ 'connect.sess': 'j:{"data":{"pseudo":"a","idplayer":100}}' }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same yesterday and this was my solution:

```
io.configure(function(){
    io.set('authorization', function(data, accept){
        if(data.headers.cookie){
            data.cookie = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
            return accept(null, true);
        }
        return accept('error', false);
    });
});
```

now you can access via `socket.handshake.cookie['cookie']`

hope it helps.